# biblatex & references: unpublished style with eprint

Tags: biblatex

The biblatex unpublished style does not offer the eprint & eprinttype fields. Would you know how to add them (if possible).

Comment: How can I use the sign "&" in the reference list in LaTex?
For example "Chaos, Solitons & Fractals"

Comment: If you're using `biblatex`, try `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}`.

Comment: @Roz Better post your own question separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea (a work with eprint information may be considered as "published"), but here's how to do it: In the bibliography driver for @unpublished, the bibmacro `url+urdate` needs to be replaced by the bibmacro `doi+eprint+url` (which also includes `url+urldate`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{unpublished}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
%  \newunit\newblock% DELETED
%  \iftoggle{bbx:url}% DELETED
%    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}% DELETED
%    {}% DELETED
  \newunit\newblock% NEW
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}% NEW
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  eprint = {(eprint_information)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It looks very sophisticated. Please, visit the following link `http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00551910/fr/` to understand the relevance of my question. If you click on "Récupérer au format...bibtex" [top right], you'll see that the document is referred to as unpublished but still there is an access to arxiv [bottom of the page] with a link to a pdf file. There may be a better way to reference such documents that I am not aware of.

Comment: @pluton. `biblatex` takes a somewhat different line on 'unpublished' to the traditional BibTeX styles, reflecting the changes in publication in the internet age. So I'd agree with lockstep's comment that this really is not an 'unpublished' item in a `biblatex` sense.

Comment: @Joseph: so what should be used instead? Thanks "paperlyunpublished"? :)

Comment: @pluton. 'article': `biblatex` deals with the document type, and whether it's on dead trees or not it's still an article.

Comment: @Joseph: correct but the paper of interest is not related to any official journal, that's pretty much what makes it unpublished. I do not know how to reflect that.

Comment: as a working physicist, an arxiv paper is a preprint, not a published article. Even arxiv asks not to use @article for arxiv articles (try to export citation of any arxiv preprint that is not already published somewhere else)